# Skype Rest API Auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, skypedeveloper

Any good resources on how to do [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/chat/#authentication)? I tried doing a curl, but I have no clue how to get my app-secret. I've gone [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) to get the client/app id. And when I submit the curl it verifies that it's a valid client/app id.

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=<your-app-id>&client_secret=<your-app-secret>&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Answer (score 3):

On the first page you linked to (https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/chat/#authentication), there's a link later on in that section:

> For more information on obtaining an OAuth2 token see the [OAuth 2.0
>   Authorization Code Flow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/).

On that page, in the section titled 'Request an Access Token,' it provides a more detailed description of the purpose of the POST request you're trying to send including descriptions of all the parameters, including 'client-secret.' It says the following about client-secret:

> The application secret that you created in the app registration portal
>   for your app. It should not be used in a native app, because
>   client_secrets cannot be reliably stored on devices. It is required
>   for web apps and web APIs, which have the ability to store the
>   client_secret securely on the server side.

So assuming your app is a web app, when you registered it there should have been a section in the app registration portal (the [second link in your original post](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList)) where you are able to generate a client_secret. That section looks like this:

[image: app registration portal secret generation section]

If you didn't do that initially, you should still be able to go back and edit the registration to add another secret.

Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: How do I use the Password/Public Key? I tried inputing it but it got rejected. When I created it, I got a pfx file. What is this?

Comment: A .pfx file is a private public key pair - I think for a web app you will need to click the button on the left: "generate new password" and use that as your client secret instead.

Can you provide a little more specific info? Like exactly what requests you sent with all the parameters you specified, and the full text of all responses you received (with any sensitive information replaced). You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor web traffic if you're on Windows.